# Access firebase data by key using child_added in React componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm experimenting with Firebase and I've written code like the following before but for some reason I am not getting what I expect.

When the React component below mounts I expect the `this.state.clients` array to be populated with the queried  firebase data. The problem is that when the component loads `this.state.clients` is empty (and there are no errors). I've also included a snap shot image of my schema. I am using the "reatime database" and not the newer "Cloud Firestore".

Thank you!

[image]

**Code**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

class Dashboard extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            clients: []
        }    

      this.clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients')

    }

    componentDidMount(){
       this.clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
       const client = snapshot.val();
       client.key = snapshot.key;
       this.setState({ clients: this.state.clients.concat( client ) })
     });
    }



    render(){
      console.log(this.state.clients);   // <---- is an empty array after component mounts but *should* contain data per the above firebase query

        return(
          <div>


           <h2>All Clients </h2>

          </div>

        )
    }
}

export default Dashboard
```

Comment: Is your `child_added` callback being called?

Comment: Doesn't look like it but I don't know why. I assumed this is the way you get all the respective data on componentDidMount

Comment: Does your client have permission to read the data? Check your logging output for relevant error messages, specifically "permission denied".

Comment: No, no errors. When I console.log this.clientsRef in componentDidMount it returns the object. Yes the client has permission.

Comment: Hmm... in that case I don't see what's going wrong. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I forgot to set the read privileges in the "rules" tab

Answer (score 0):

It's an empty array because you declared it an empty array in the constructor. The 'child added' event hasn't fired yet. If you go to your firebase console and manually add an item to 'clients' then this will trigger the 'child added' event and the event will show up in your UI. Replace 'child_added' with 'value' if you want the value of all existing events onload.

Comment: When I use "value" the callback still doesn't fire.

Comment: change `import firebase from 'firebase/app';` to `import firebase from 'firebase';`, if you want to import modules you will have to import the database module as well.

Comment: It still doesn't call the callback